# How do I perform a clean navigation between screens?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I gotta create a UITabbarController and also Embed In a UINavigationController, to create a nice navigation system with TopBar and also the BottomBar. However, I feel I'm doing something wrong, because when I run the app I can't see the UITabBar with my two screens as options to navigate through. Can you guys take a look please?

***Storyboard:***

[image]
***Simulator 1***

[image]

***Simulator 2***

[image]

***That's how the UITabBar should looks like:***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct structure

You have

1- Add another VC embed in a navigation

2- Control-drag from the tabBar to that `UINavigationController` and select `viewControllers`

[image]

//

And you will get this

//

[image]

Comment: Hello dude! Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. I really appreciate your interest on helping me

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

TabBar -> Navigation Controller -> 1st ViewController with the tableView

TabBar -> Navigation Controller -> 2nd ViewController

but what you have is this:

TabBar -> Navigation Controller -> 1st ViewController with the tableView ->
 2nd ViewController

Add another Navigation Controller connect it to the Tab Bar Controller (relationship segue: view controllers),
now connect your second view controller to the Navigation Controller (relationship segue: root view controller)